# Dynamic route params in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am familiar with angularjs

When I want to add my routing to my application I use `$routeProvider`

In `$routeProvider.when()`, I define routes.

How to define a route If I have a directory browser like structure like:

```
http://myfolderbrowserapp.com/:folder1/:folder2/.../:folderN
```

Is it possible with angularjs like:

```
$routeProvider.when('/**', {
    template:'template'
})
```

Is this possible with angular routing? If not is there a workaround?

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [$routeProvider docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

> path can contain named groups starting with a colon and ending with a
>   star: e.g.:name*. All characters are eagerly stored in $routeParams
>   under the given name when the route matches.

So you could define

```
$routeProvider.when('/:folders*', {
    template:'template'
})
```

And then (in controller e.g.)

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
    if (angular.isDefined($routeParams.folders))
        var foldersArray = $routeParams.folders.split('/');
});
```

However the path definition `/:folders*` is too generic and would probably be matched even in cases when you do not want to (don't know how your other paths look like).